# Re-export namespace using type specifier

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to re-export a namespace that was imported using the `type` specifier? In the below example (that doesn't work properly) I'm importing the `tslib` namespace from `typescript/lib/tsserverlibrary.js` and then trying to re-export the `tslib.server.protocol` sub-namespace from it while also including the `type` specifier.

```
import type tslib from 'typescript/lib/tsserverlibrary.js';

export type tsp = typeof tslib.server.protocol;
```

I've tried both:

```
export type tsp = typeof tslib.server.protocol;
```

which doesn't work at import-sites because `tsp` is a type and not a namespace anymore:

> 'tsp' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here. ​typescript(2702)

I've also tried:

```
export import tsp = tslib.server.protocol;
```

but that errors with:

> An import alias cannot reference a declaration that was imported using 'import type'. ​typescript(1380)